# Microsoft JDBC Driver is not working after upgrade from Java 1.7 to Java 1.8

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

After upgrading from Java 1.7 to Java 1.8, I am getting the below error when having *sqljdbc4.jar* (version 4.0) in my build path. How can I resolve this problem?

[image: This is the error I get]

Comment: And please, add the stack trace as text in the question rather than a picture.

Comment: Have you already checked the JDBC vendor information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937724.aspx)?

Answer (score 3):

In the details section of the [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774) for the driver, the Java compliance is listed:

> - The Microsoft JDBC Driver **4.2** for SQL Server is JDBC 4.2 compliant and runs on the Java Development Kit (JDK) version **5.0, 6.0, 7.0, and 8.0**.
> - The Microsoft JDBC Driver **4.1** for SQL Server is JDBC 4.0 compliant and runs on the Java Development Kit (JDK) version **5.0, 6.0, and 7.0**.
> - The Microsoft JDBC Driver **4.0** for SQL Server is JDBC 4.0 compliant and runs on the Java Development Kit (JDK) version **5.0 or 6.0**.

In other words, you need to upgrade to version 4.2 in order to be sure that it works with Java 8.